# C# dictionary with few different values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create a data store to allow me to store some data.

The first idea was to create a dictionary which could have one key to the some values, but i have no idea how to store few different vaues,  for example i need two values (string and Image). Can someone suggest how to realize that?

How else could I store this information??

Comment: Create a new type, `MyType`, that holds a string and an image. Then make a `Dictionary<TKey, MyType>`.

Comment: Would wrapping a string and image object in another class1, then creating a dictionary <key, class1object> work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OOP world usually the data is represented in classes, which define it's structure, behavior and responsibilities. From your example to store string and image you could create class:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public byte[] Image { get;set;}
}
```

and then your dictionary would be like:

```
Dictionary<string,Article> data;
```

Comment: can you add example : if i coll data["first element"] i get (for exaple) string "car" and picture of car fro resources?

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, but it works like this:
string car = data["first"].Name; byte[] carImage = data["first"].Image

Comment: how to get using class article that i need?

Answer (score 1):

Well there can be several approaches to achieve this.

1) create a class which has `string` and `image` as its members. Then store the instance of this class as value.

2) use `Tuple<String, Image>` as value

Answer (score 0):

Since in c# all objects derive from object, you may use object as the value of dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> dataStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

With this way you can store any type of object in your dictionary but don't forget to make the right cast.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store different data according to one key? For example "key1" ->(Name, Age, Birthday) or do you want to store a different type of data under ache key? For example "key1"->Name , "key2"->Age, "key3"->Birthday?
In the first case, you should create a new class for you values and store an instance of the the class under each key. For the second case you can create an dictionary and make the value of the type "object". Then you can store any object data type to the keys.